# How to create multiple objects based on dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, steam

Basically what i'm doing, is trying to create my own steam market JSON, by HTML parsing.

Example of how I'm currently doing that :

```
var url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730'
var itemDiv = $("<div></div>")
$.get(url).success(function(r){
    data = $(r).find('stuff i need')
    itemDiv.append(data)
})
```

and now say I wanted to find names of the items in the div, i would do something like :

```
itemDiv.find('x').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).find("y").text()
    // console.log(name) [or do whatever is needed ect]
})
```

As I mentioned before, I need to return objects based on that data in the format of:

```
var item = {name:"",price:0}
```

However, things like price will always be changing.

Based on the data thats in the div, the final product would look along the lines of :

```
var x = {name:"a",price:1}
var x2 = {name:"a2",price:2}
```

How do I go about doing this? I thought maybe i could store the data in an array, and then do something like

```
for(x in y){
return object
}
```

or something along those lines.

Sorry if this seems like a bonehead question, I'm pretty new to javascript.

clarification: i'm trying to figure out how to return multiple objects based on the data inside the div.

Comment: Saving multiple objects in an array is the right way to go. But just so you know a return statement immediately exits the loop (and the function). You should probably clarify your question. What are you exactly looking for here?

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand what you're trying to do. If you are saving these objects in an array, you have all the data you need. Any action you intend to take on these objects can be done by iterating through this array. Or are you trying to save these different objects into different variables? If so, why?

Comment: @satish An option would be to store the data into an array, I was wondering if there would be any other way to do it, and if so, what would it be. I guess i didn't nail the question when i wrote this, sorry. But once i have the data in an array, how would i create objects based on that? Say i have two arrays, one called price, and one called name. Each array would have five values, so I would need to return 5 objects in the format of item = {name:"",price:0}, Thats basically what im trying to ask.

Comment: I posted a response based on your comment. That should give you the collection of objects that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that builds an array of objects based on two arrays (assuming they are of equal length).

```
function buildStocks() {
    // Names and prices can also be passed as function arguments
    var names = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 
    var prices = [1, 2, 3];
    var result = []; // Array of these objects

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        result.push({
            name: names[i],
            price: prices[i]
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks for the help.